# creating a new project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional leads to an infinite loop, then crash

Tags: visual-studio-2013

New install of VS 2013 Pro, Windows 8

Creating a new win32 console project appears to work - but after it gets done creating the project, the create project dialog opens again. If I try to continue with that, I have to give that project a different name to create it. Then the dialog opens again. Repeats indefinitely.

If I click "cancel" instead of "create" to get out of the loop, the application stops working.

Comment: Try a repair of Visual Studio.  Otherwise, uninstall and re-install.

Comment: Didn't help. I'll check their support site.

Comment: Also, selecting "empty project" under c++ -> general causes the error "Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))", then the app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing the installation and a reboot (may not be required) fixed this for me in Windows 7.